# Best approach for On demand loading of tabs and form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs

I am developing an app using angularJS. This application has about 5 tabs and this is mainly a form and a single submit option for all tabs.(similar to employee data maintenance) The form is loaded with data of the user when the page gets loaded and user can edit and resubmit the form.

Since loading all the 5 tabs in the initial page load will effect the load time of the page , so i am planning to use on demand loading of contents and API.

1st approach:
One thing i can do is loading only 1st tab on initial load and load the other tabs based on click on the tab and using ng-include to include partial views. So in the end user can submit the form and client side validation can be done easily.In this case page will have DOM elements of all activated tabs.

2nd approach: By using [routing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808213/Developing-a-Large-Scale-Application-with-a-Single) (i am not much familiar with this). But from my understanding this logic will replace the DOM of a tab when user switches tab unlike 1st approach. So there is a need of using service or some other technique to save the data. But i want to retain the DOM of previous active tab even when tab is switched. So can it be done?

Finally, What is the best approach among above two OR is there any other good techniques to achieve same?

Answer (score 1):

I think Option 2 would work best for you. AngularUI router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) would help with this above the standard ng-router.

Rather than save the DOM between tab switches, you could just save the data and re-bind when you switch tabs.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any technique to save the DOM? Also what is the problem with approach 1? Any reasons?

Comment: Can u pls tell me how i can save all scope variables associate with ng-model when i switch routes